# Delete query execution is very slow when run inside bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to run following query inside a bash script.

When it is executed from mysql command promt, execution time was 0.06sec.

```
mysql> delete from assign_history where offer_id not in 
->('7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','32','157','211','240','241','242','273',
->'274','275','310','312','313','314','326','328','329','333','334','335','336',
->'337','342','343','355','362','374','375','376','378','379','383','384','409','411') 
->and date(action_date) < "2015-06-25" order by id limit 1000;
Query OK, 1000 rows affected (0.06 sec)
```

But when run it inside a bash script, it takes more than 2 minutes.

```
[root@localhost umap]# cat ./history_del.sh 
#! /bin/bash
echo $(date)
mysql -uroot -ppassword db_offers -e "delete from assign_history where offer_id not in ('7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','32','157','211','240','241','242','273','274','275','310','312','313','314','326','328','329','333','334','335','336','337','342','343','355','362','374','375','376','378','379','383','384','409','411') and date(action_date) < "2015-06-25" limit 1000;"
echo $(date)

[root@localhost umap]# ./history_del.sh  
Wed Aug 26 19:08:45 IST 2015
Wed Aug 26 19:10:48 IST 2015
```

I also tried with "mysql -Bse" options. No improvement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas?

First, you need to escape double-quotes inside the query string: \"2015-06-25\" (try to output your query with echo and you'll see, why ). I dont know, how your request works without properly specified quotes...

Second, it is better and preferred to place your long-line-request in the file, so your command-line will look like this:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword db_offers <YOUR_FILE
```

Request in YOUR_FILE will be the same as in the mysql prompt (of course, you dont need to escape double-quotes here).

And yes, when you call mysql utility - it can take unpredictably long time to connect to MySQL server, so 2 minutes include this time (but 0.06 sec in mysql prompt doesnt!), so you cant say, how much time does it take to connect to server and how much - to send and execute your query.

To know, how much time does it take to connect to mysql server, try to execute (wait several seconds after previous run of the mysql utility) any empty query, such as:

```
time mysql -u user -ppassword -Bs <<<'select null'
```

Comment: Replacing double quotes with single quotes solved the problem. '2015-06-25'